# What are valid values for framework.session.storage_id?

Tags: symfony, config

In the Symfony configuration there is an entry `framework.session.storage_id`. This setting also appears in the default config on the [Symfony configuration documentation](http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/configuration/framework.html) but it is not explained. My assumption is that it defines where session data is stored on the server side.

Values I have seen for this entry include `session.storage.mock_file`, `session.storage.native` and `session.storage.filesystem`. I am unsure of what these values exactly mean (e.g. what is the difference between a mock file and a filesystem?) and also think that this is not the complete list of possible values.

So what exactly does this configuration key control and what values are valid?

Comment: I mean why would you put it in the docs... that makes everything too easy!

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Valid values for `framework.session.storage_id` are following:

- `session.storage.mock_file` - for testing. It doesn't start session at all.
- `session.storage.filesystem` - for testing. It is an alias for `session.storage.mock_file`.
- `session.storage.native` - default implementation using defined session handler
- `session.storage.php_bridge` - [for legacy apps](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/session/php_bridge.html)

From developer perspective, there is a `session` service that abstracts working with session. `session` service depends on some *session storage service*. *Session storage* implements session management from PHP perspective (calling `session_start()` function for example). *Storage* also depends on some *session handler*. *Handler* is implementation of `\SessionStorage` and it tells how and where will be session physically stored.

[This three layer design](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/2.6/src/Symfony/Bundle/FrameworkBundle/Resources/config/session.xml) allows creating *storage* for testing which does not call `session_start()` at all and does not use handler (`session.storage.mock_file`). Or creating of *handler* that can store and load session from anywhere (`session.storage.native`). `session.storage.php_bridge` solves situation when `session_start()` is called by external PHP code (not by Symfony *session storage*).

I hope it is clear to understand.

Comment: Thanks! The XML file you linked also specifies a `session.storage.metadata_bag`, is that also a possible value?

Comment: I don't think, because metadata_bag is used as dependency for all storages that I have listed in my post.

Comment: "for testing. It doesn't start session at all." Does this mean there is no session and thus no persistence? How can you test your software without persistence?

Answer (score 9):

For Symfony 6.x, it has changed. As an example, this worked for me:

```
framework:
   test: true
   session:
       storage_factory_id: session.storage.factory.mock_file
```

Answer (score 4):

Session management in Symfony is based on two main rules.

1. Symfony must start the session.
2. The Symfony sessions are designed to replace the use of PHP native functions `session_*()` and `$_SESSION` global.

However, some exceptions exist. Sometimes it may be necessary to integrate Symfony in a legacy application, which starts the session with `session_start()`.
With **`session.storage.php_bridge`** directive, you can manage the session using a special gateway that is designed to allow to Symfony working with a session that was started outside the framework.

In goal to make the code using sessions testable, **`session.storage.mock_file`** directive allows to simulate the flow of a PHP session without starting it really.