# Symfony 3.0.1 CSRF token present but invalid

Tags: php, forms, symfony

I am having this strange issue with a fresh Symfony 3.0.1 installation. I generated a new CRUD Controller with a Form PostType which contains an url and a title. Nothing fancy.

The form is rendered as expected. It contains both my url field and title field. Inside the form the hidden input field _token is also rendered.

When submitting this form, i am getting all the time the following error:

```
The CSRF token is invalid. Please try to resubmit the form.
```

So the token is added to the form, it contains a value, i have a constant PHP session cookie value, it is just that this token invalid.

I have searched for other answers but the similar questions are all caused by the absence of a _token input.

This problem also occurs in Symfony 3.0.2/3.0.3.

Comment: There is no Symfony 3.1.

Comment: 3.1 is the dev-master. Look it up here : https://packagist.org/packages/symfony/symfony#dev-master

Comment: add some code that creates and processes form

Comment: Does it work in 3.0?  dev-master is of course a work in progress so it could have errors I suppose.  Seems unlikely that this sort of error would have been merged.

Comment: Tested on 3.0.2, and there i get the same error. Will add code now.

Comment: I just set up the FOSUserBundle and when i fill in the register form, i am getting the same CSRF error. So i doubt if this is something in my code. Does CSRF require any other configuration that i am not aware of?

Comment: I debugged the application and it turned out that the CsrfTokenManager couldnt store the generated token in to the sessionStorage. Once i fugured this out, i changed the sessions save_path:   "%kernel.root_dir%/../var/sessions/%kernel.environment%" to ~. That fixed it. Now i am gonna figure out whats the issue with the old save_path.

Comment: @yellowmen, check if you var/sessions/ folder has writable permissions

Comment: @yellowmen: Changing the setting to default "~" also works for me. I double checked the permissions of the "var/sessions" path. They are writeable for the webserver and also files get created. But they are empty. I think, its a symfony3 bug.

Comment: Does someone know if it has been fixed since then in last releases ?

Comment: @yellowmen I tried your solution and it didn't work :( what else could it be? I am using the built-in SF server (server:fun), could that be it?

Comment: @yellowmen it helped me too but I don't know why. In var/sessions symfony created dev directory and put there files. But it didn't work. on prod it works, not on dev. After setting path to ~ it works on dev too.

Comment: I am having the sample problem on Symfony 3.4.9, the error is only on dev. On prod it works without any problems. On dev CsrfTokenManager couldnt store the generated token in to the sessionStorage. Permission are not a problem in my case. dev and prod have identical permissions.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

In my case it was that the `var/sessions/` folder wasn't writable. The default is var/sessions which is set at config.yml.

```
session:
    # http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/configuration/framework.html#handler-id
    handler_id:  session.handler.native_file
    save_path:   "%kernel.root_dir%/../var/sessions/%kernel.environment%"
```

Make sure you have `var/ folders` writable.

```
chmod 775 -R var/sessions/
chmod 775 -R var/log/
chmod 775 -R var/cache/
```

Comment: This indeed was my problem. Thank you!

Comment: It did it also for me. Thanks !

Comment: You should accept an answer so your question won't appear unsolved.

Comment: It was my problem too, Thank you so much!

Answer (score 9):

I just had a similar issue with Symfony 3.2

> The CSRF token is invalid. Please try to resubmit the form.

After hours, we finally found the issue was related to session.cookie_secure (https):

Our production environment uses https, thus forces cookies to be secured over https. The dev environment used http. After moving the dev from HTTP to HTTPS, problem was fixed.

Comment: PERFECT. REAL SOLUTİON

Answer (score 1):

I'm using Symfony 3.2.1 and it's working on one machine but not the other. No idea why.

@Shrihari his answer led me to the following solution.

My project also has `cookie_secure: true`.
I updated `config_dev.yml` and added `cookie_secure: false` to the file.

```
framework:
    session:
        cookie_secure: false
```

This worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to be a bug in symfony version >3.0, <3.0.3.

As @yellowmen pointed out, changing the `framework.session.save_path` in the `config.yml` fixes the problem.

Comment: I have 3.1.3 and this is happening to me, none of these solutions worked.  Is it a problem with using `server:run`?

Answer (score 0):

The bug is also present in 3.0.4.
`save_path: ~` worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

I experienced a similar problem with Symfony 4.2 when switching from `dev` to `test` environment.

I had the following setting in my `framework.yaml` file:

```
framework:
    session:
        storage_id: session.storage.mock_file
```

### Solution:

Removing the `storage_id: session.storage.mock_file`-setting solved the problem.

**Important:** You probably have to clear the cache for this to take effect.

For more information about the `storage_id`-configuration option also see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29563414/3105311).

Answer (score 0):

I had the same on env=dev but not on preprod (symfony 4.4)

--Solution--

There was missing sessions dir in the root
I have created one then the problem solved.

cheers